# Gathering all content on the screen (console buffer) to create a changing character

Tags: batch-file, console

I am creating a batch file where there is a actively changing character from `\` to `/` and to do this you obviously need to clear the screen, output everything that was already on the screen and then add the next character at the end.

This is not too hard when I already know what is on the screen, however I am trying to make this a program which can be called by other programs at any time. That is why I need a means of gathering all the current content on the screen, so that when my program is called it can:

1. Gather everything on the screen to a variable or to a temp file
2. Clear the screen and output its content + char1
3. Clear the screen and output its content + char2
4. Repeat 2-3 number of specified times

I can manage 2-4 I just need help with 1.

Any suggestions? Is this even possible?

Thanks in advance Mona.

Comment: If the spinner is in the last printed line, it's possible to change it without clearing the screen. With a `CR` character like foxidrive shown or with a backspace character

Comment: Did the `CR` or `BS` tricks that foxidrive/jeb mentioned solved your problem? If not, perhaps my [CursorPos](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3428&p=17216&hilit=CursorPos.exe#p17216) auxiliary program could help you (look for program #6). This program lets you to move the cursor to a certain position _and_ read the character at that screen position!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't an answer for you but it shows a spinner and you may not have seen the technique:

A second demonstration follows it, but it may not work as well in Windows 8 .

```
   @Echo OFF
   SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
   For /f %%a in ('copy /Z "%~dpf0" nul') Do set "CR=%%a"
   Set "busy=|/-\"
   Set /A n=0


   ::BUSY SPINNER
   For /L %%i in (0,1,10) Do (
     Set /A "n=%%i%%4"
     For /L %%n in (!n! 1 !n!) Do Set /P "=Calculating !busy:~%%n,1! !CR!"<NUL:
     PING -n 2 127.0.0.1 >NUL:
   )
   ::COUNTDOWN
   For /L %%i in (10,-1,1) Do (
     Set /P "=Backup will begin in %%i seconds.  !CR!"<NUL:
     PING -n 2 127.0.0.1 >NUL:
   )

   ::PROGRESS
   For %%i in (*) Do (
     Set /P "=Copying %%i                                    !CR!"<NUL:
     PING -n 2 127.0.0.1 >NUL:
   )
     Set /P "=Done.                                               !CR!"<NUL:

   pause
```

Here is a second demo of a rotating spinner:

```
@echo off
:jeb
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
if "%~1"==":::" goto :spinnerThread

:menuLoop
<nul set /p menu=Select menu[1 or 2]=
call :GetKey
echo(
echo Pressed '!key!'
if !key!==1 call :menu1
if !key!==2 call :menu2
if !key!==2 call :menu2
goto :menuLoop

:menu1
:menu2
call :spinnerStart
rem do some work
ping localhost -n 3  > nl
call :spinnerStop
echo Finished
exit /b

:spinnerStart
del spinnerStop.tmp > nul 2>&1
start /b "" cmd /c "%~df0" :::
exit /b

:spinnerStop
echo dummy > spinnerStop.tmp
:__spinnerStop
if exist spinnerStop.tmp goto :__spinnerStop
exit /b

:spinnerThread
for /f %%a in ('copy /Z "%~f0" nul') do set "CR=%%a"
set "spinChars=\|/-"

:spinnerLoop
set /a "spinner=(spinner + 1) %% 4"
<nul set /p ".=Waiting...!spinChars:~%spinner%,1!!CR!"
ping localhost -n 2 > nul 2>&1
if not exist spinnerStop.tmp goto :spinnerLoop
del spinnerStop.tmp > nul 2>&1
echo(
exit /b

:GetKey
set "key="
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%L in (`xcopy /L /w "%~f0" "%~f0" 2^>NUL`) do (
  if not defined key set "key=%%L"
)
set "key=%key:~-1%"
exit /b
```

Comment: wait so how does `For /f %%a in ('copy /Z "%~dpf0" nul') Do set "CR=%%a"` produce a carrage return?

Comment: It is the delayed expansion that allows it to function.  http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5405